# How do I make my obstacles (separate prefabs) appear randomly in the world?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I am using Unity in C# to code a game similar to Google's Dinosaur Run where random obstacles are spawned in the player's path which they need to jump to dodge. I have 6 different prefabs (with animations) for my obstacles which use Polygon Colliders to detect collisions. How can I use an array to randomly select one of these obstacle prefabs to spawn them at various distances apart?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObstacleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Sprite[] sprites;
    

    public int Type { get; set; }

    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    private PolygonCollider2D polygonCollider2D;

    public void Initialise()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        polygonCollider2D = GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();

        int type = Random.Range(0, sprites.Length);

        Type = type;
        spriteRenderer.sprite = sprites[type];
        
    }
}
```

Above is the code I have so far which only allows me to have sprites as obstacles whereas I want to use prefabs with set dimensions and animation properties.

Comment: You can use GameObject[] instead of Sprite[] to hold your prefabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this,

```
[Serializefield] GameObject [] prefabs;
int type = Random.Range (0, sprites.Length);
float spwanRangeX = 10f; // desired value
Vector3 spwanPos = new Vector3 (Random.Range(spwanRangeX,-spawnRangeX),0,0);
    
Instantiate (prefabs[type], spawnPos , prefabs[type].transform.rotation);
```

Comment: OP needs a solution that works with prefabs rather than sprites, but this answer is not addressing such issues. You could edit and expand it as needed.

Comment: I'm having some syntax errors when I use this script - Assets\Scripts\ObstacleController.cs(12,25): error CS0270: Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)
Assets\Scripts\ObstacleController.cs(12,30): error CS1001: Identifier expected
Assets\Scripts\ObstacleController.cs(12,41): error CS1001: Identifier expected
Assets\Scripts\ObstacleController.cs(12,56): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

Comment: Drag  prefabs into the prefabs  array slot in inspector